# How to connect K8s clusters to MongDB atlas. Whitelist all nodes ip

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, mongodb-atlas, whitelist

I'm new to K8s. One issue I experience at the moment is whitelist all IPs of k8s nodes for MongDB atlas so that my nodes can use MongDB atlas as DB services. I have read through the DOCs from MongDB and Digital Ocean. It seems that MongoDB do not support Network peering for Digital Ocean Provider. I know that I can manually add all IPs of K8s nodes to MongDB atlas. However, I don't think that is a good practices because Nodes can get replace and IP addresses can be altered. Is there a better way to fix this issue? For example, using a shell script to auto all the tasks?